# Automatically add a calendar entry

Tags: office-365, automation, outlook.com-calendar

We are using Office 365 / Outlook calendar to keep track of customer appointments.

We have certain forms on our website for customers to request an appointment. After such a form is submitted, a calendar entry should automatically be created for the date/time that the customer selected in the form.

I realize I can just send the calendar entry as an email attachment, but that would still require the admin to manually "accept" the event so that it is added to their calendar.

Is it possible to automatically create a calendar event, perhaps by auto-accepting all events sent to a certain email address, or via another channel?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to test it to be sure it works how you need it, but it may make sense to setup your appointment Calendar as a Shared Mailbox or Resource Calendar, then run the [PowerShell cmdlet Set-CalendarProcessing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps) on the tenant.

[Connect to your exchange online tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) and execute

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity <INSERT CALENDAR NAME> -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept -DeleteComments $false -AddOrganizerToSubject $true -AllowConflicts $true
```

where `<INSERT CALENDAR NAME>` is the name of your resource calendar.